# tapply and mean provide different answers

Tags: r, mean, tapply

I'm working with a toy data set. I noticed that asking the mean() by subsetting the data and using tapply() on the full dataset provide different answers.

```r
dat<-data.frame(x1=c(1.34,1.19,0.89,0.88,0.98,0.85,0.93,0.87,1.02,0.96,
                     0.77,1.17,1.12,1.61,1.18,1.00,0.88,1.08,1.12,0.69,
                     1.29,1.16,0.94,0.94,0.58,0.87,1.11,1.08,0.92,1.23,
                     0.94,0.41,0.57,0.19,1.13,0.33,0.60,0.16,0.33,0.77,
                     1.44,0.62,0.70,0.77,0.47,0.44,0.28,0.22),
                 x2=c("+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+",
                      "+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/+","+/-","+/-",
                      "+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-",
                      "+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-","+/-",
                      "-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-",
                      "-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-","-/-")
             )
 mean(dat$x1[which(dat$x2=="-/-")])
[1] 0.56
 mean(dat$x1[which(dat$x2=="+/-")])
[1] 0.97
 mean(dat$x1[which(dat$x2=="+/+")])
[1] 1
 tapply(X=dat$x1,INDEX=dat$x2,FUN=mean)
 -/-  +/-  +/+ 
0.56 0.97 1.04 
 mean(c(1.34,1.19,0.89,0.88,0.98,0.85,0.93,0.87,1.02,0.96,
       0.77,1.17,1.12,1.61))
[1] 1
```

How is tapply returning 1.04 when it should be 1?

Comment: When I run your code I got no differences. (3.6.1). Have you turned on round?

Comment: I can't reproduce this and get the mean as `1.041429` ... I suspect you may be limiting the number of digits that are printed.

Comment: Wow. If I add options(digits=13) to the top of the code it works fine. Is that default behavior? I don't remember turning round on  -- how does that happen? I started a fresh R session and it worked as expected.

Comment: it is not the default which i think is seven (options()$digits) ... perhaps you have done this in a previous session and loaded the workspace?

Comment: Checkout the `par()` and `options()` variables. They might be modified within some usual chunks of code (like the use of `par()$mfrow` for data visualization). Also, you may have modified it carelessly.